# (almost) Pure C instead of C preprocessor

Tags: c, compiler

Why isn't (almost) pure C used instead of the C preprocessor?

Sure I understand it would be a little more verbose. For example:

```
#define PI 3.14159
```

If we had regular C as preprocessor language, the above could be rewritten to something like:

```
#define PI {printf("3.14159");}
```

The idea is to not substitute `{printf(...)}` for `PI` but to run the code from the macro definition and splice the output of that code in the place of `PI`.

Yes, it's more verbose, but for more complex stuff I think it would help alot. Also, going with this design, programmers wouldn't have to learn another language (namely the C preprocessor) in order to write macros.

So, are there any other reason except the verbosity that the C preprocessor is not just pure C (with perhaps small modifications, like the addition of the `define` keyword)?

Comment: You can calculate the area of a circle with `area = PI*radius*radius` with the first example. Your second example is a syntax error. This question is confusing.

Comment: Where would `printf` in the macro come from? Usually it's a library function declared in the header `stdio.h` which... is included using the C preprocessor. See the issue?

Comment: I believe that he is intending that the compiler executes the `printf`.

Comment: @whatsisname I think the idea is to not substitute `{printf(...)}` for `PI` but to run the code from the macro definition and splice the output of that code in the place of `PI`.

Comment: @delnan: If that's the idea, then I cannot imagine the horror of trying to debug software with significant usage of those. The preprocessor as-is is bad enough.

Comment: @delnan: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: @delnan: Yes, including stdio.h is an issue. But that issue can be resolved with two preprocessor directives: regular a ``include`` and a new directive: ``preprocessor_include``, couln't it?

Comment: One can argue that when **[properly used](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/116308/22815)**, most `#define`s are valid language constructs: expressions. (Note: that linked question is a _bad_ example, the answers all explain why).

Comment: Look into [D language](http://dlang.org/)

Comment: Wouldn't such a system fall foul of the halting problem?  You would be unable to determine if it's even possible to compile a program in finite time.

Comment: @SimonB When you run arbitrary code at compile time, it's indeed impossible to check whether compilation terminates. But the same check is already impossible for the resulting program, and it's almost never a problem in practice. Also, numerous newer languages do run arbitrary code at compile time, and their users get along just fine. A more common problem is that compilation terminates but takes rather long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you suggest is possible with more modern languages. C was invented at a time when compiler technology was far too primitive to allow this kind of programmable compilation pipeline. Furthermore, most programmers knew of no use for such a mechanism.

Even today it's difficult to construct a compiler that can permit such programming. It's easy to specify the behaviour in such simple cases but far more difficult to consider what it should do in the general case.

Comment: It's certainly hard to give satisfactory syntax and semantics to compile-time metaprogramming, but then again the C preprocessor doesn't look too good in hindsight either. Working fully programmable macros are a Lisp thing, and while they didn't spring from McCarthy's mind fully grown, they [existed in the sixties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3065606/395760). Admittedly, interpreting Lisp at read-time is easier than interpreting (even a stripped-down dialect of) C.

Comment: The C preprocessor is not great, but it was actually implementable.

Comment: And I supplied evidence a similarly not-great macro processor might be implementable. I'm too young to make definite statements about the capabilities of 60's technology but so far you only asserted that "compiler technology was far too primitive".

Comment: @delnan: Of course, you argue that Lisp implemented similar features, but there's little evidence that it was competitive with C at the time. "Some dude implemented it" != "It was reasonably implementable".